# Почему методы MonoBehaviour не требуют написания модификаторов доступа?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-faq

Почему в классе `MonoBehaviour` функции `Awake`, `Start`, `Update`, `OnDestroy`, `OnCollision` и т.д. пишутся без модификаторов и их написание не обязательно как в интерфейсе или абстрактном классе.

Просмотрев материнские классы `MonoBehaviour` : `Behaviour` : `Component` : `Object` я даже не увидел объявления этих функций.

Comment: Я, конечно, не варился в этой каше, но так тихо подозреваю, что там обыкновенная рефлексия, завязанная на конкретных названиях методов, поэтому их нет там ни в каком виде.

Comment: @John нету там рефлексии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Reflection` там не используется.

При первом обращении к `MonoBehaviour` скрипту в рантайме (не важно, Mono или IL2CPP) все эти магические методы кешируются.

Если у вас в `MonoBehaviour` определённ подобный магический метод (тот же `Update`), то он добавляется в специальный список.

В самой игре Unity потом прогоняет этот список и вызывает эти магические методы.

Если бы эти методы были определены в базовом абстрактом классе/интерфейсе (а таких [магических методов десятки](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)), то в вашем скрипте вам бы пришлось их все переопределять, а так вы определяете только нужное. А если не определяете, то Unity даже не будет пытаться вызвать эти методы.

Comment: Если бы эти методы были определены в базовом классе, то их можно было бы объявить с модификатором virtual и ничего бы не нужно было переопределять.

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень прозаично.

Модификатор доступа есть всегда, даже если он не указан явно. Если модификатор не указан - используется "по умолчанию" **private**

[Ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) *"<...> По умолчанию уровень доступа к членам класса и членам структуры, включая вложенные классы и структуры, является закрытым <...>"*

Comment: `private` я видел, прописывая `Start` автоматом дописывалось `private Start () {}`. Но я не понимаю как описана функция в материнском классе, нельзя же написать `private virtual Start`, ведь доступа к private у наследуемого класса не будет.

Comment: Если я ничего не путаю, то в родительском классе нет всех этих методов (Start, Update и пр.). Есть только "зарезервированные" имена методов для вызова их средствами рефлексии.

Если Вам необходимо в своем классе, который наследуется от другого Вашего класса-наследника от `Monobehaviour`, определить такие методы - то используйте `public virtual void Start(или др.)` или `protected virtual void Start(или др. метод)`. И тогда механизм наследования будет работать как и должен.